# MVC How do I create a form for a model which contains lists as properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

So I have this simple model:

```
public class OptOut
    {
        public int optOutID { get; set; }
        public bool hasOptedOut { get; set; }        
        public List<Cohort> list { get; set; }

        public OptOut()
        {
            List<Cohort> list = new List<Cohort>();
            list.Add(new Cohort());
            list.Add(new Cohort());
            list.Add(new Cohort());
            list.Add(new Cohort());
            this.list = list;
        }

    }
```

Where as you can see one of the properties is a `List` of `Cohort` objects. The `Cohort` object has some simple boolean properties:

```
public class Cohort
    {
        public bool ukft { get; set; }
        public bool ukpt { get; set; }
        ...etc
    }
```

I want to create a form which will loop through the list of `Cohort` objects.

So in my `Controller` I pass the model to the `View`:

```
public ActionResult Page()
        {                        
            return View(new OptOut());
        }
```

And then in the html I create a form like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("OptedOut", "Home"))
        {            var m = Model.list;

            <div id="radios" class="form-group" style="margin-top:25px;">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.hasOptedOut, true) <span style="margin-right:8px;">Yes</span>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.hasOptedOut, false) <span>No</span> <br />

                //here I would normally loop through the list but I'm changing only the first element for testing purposes
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => m.ElementAt(0).ukft, true) <span style="margin-right:8px;">Yes</span>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => m.ElementAt(0).ukft, false) <span>No</span> <br />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/>
            </div>
        }
```

So far so good. As you can see, I've added 2 sets of radio buttons - one for the simple `hasOptedOut` boolean property in the `OptOut` model and one for the `ukft` property of the first element in the `List`.

Now when I select yes (`true`) in both sets of radio buttons, I should expect to see `hasOptedOut = true` and the first `ukft = true` for the `Cohort` object in the `List`. So I get the model in the controller after `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OptedOut(Dlhe.Smart.Models.OptOut optout)
{                
    return View("some_view");
}
```

And `hasOptedOut` is indeed true. However, `ukft` remains false in the List. So I assume it's not so simple for `Lists`, but how do I fix this?

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I have tried doing this, with no luck:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OptedOut", "Home"))
        {            var m = Model.list;
            for (int i=0; i<Model.list.Count(); i++) {

                <div id="radios" class="form-group" style="margin-top:25px;">

                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => m[i].ukft, true) <span style="margin-right:8px;">Yes</span>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => m[i].ukft, false) <span>No</span> <br />
                </div>                
            }

                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:25px;">
                    <input id="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/>
                </div>
        }
```

Comment: You need to use a `for` loop (or custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Cohort`) - e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < Model.list.Count; i++) { @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m[i].ukft, true) ....}`

Comment: I recommend reading this article. It'll only take 10 minutes and you will instantly become a guru at model binding collections - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't see how what you've suggested makes any difference to what I've written but I tried it anyway and unfortunately it's still not updating the ukft property

Comment: @heymega I've read it just about an hour ago - I'm looking for a different solution

Comment: It does make a difference. Inspect the html you have generated with both methods. In order to bind to a collection your controls need to be named `name="list[0].ukft"`, `name="list[1].ukft"` etc. Your currently generating duplicate `name` and `id` (invalid html) attributes and nothing posts back that matched you model. All that is happening is the `DefaultModelBinder` is creating a new instance of `OptOut` with 4 new instances of `Cohort` all with the default `false` value

Comment: What is so hard about following my instructions? Look at the html that your now generating - its `name="m[0].ukft"`. Does you model have a collection named `m`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke What is so hard about reading my code? The name is not the problem because if it was getting confused then I wouldn't be able to separately select a radio in each of the rows. If you look closely, I've defined m as Model.list. If you look more closely, and actually read the OP, I had firstly tried with creating a set of radios only for ONE element in the list - which means your argument that the reason it's not working is due to duplicate name values is invalid.

Comment: @sparta223, The name **is** the problem. You need to understand the basics of model binding. You original code produces radio buttons with `name="ukft"`, your second attempt produces radio buttons with `name="m[0].ukft"`. Neither will bind to your model on post back because your model does not contain a property named `ukft` (1st case) or a collection property named `m` (2nd case). It does however contain a collection property named `list` which contains objects with a property named `ukft`, therefore the names must be `list[0].ukft`. Your must use a `for` loop or an `EditorTemplate`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok I understand you now. I will let you know if it has worked when I try it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think is to create an EditorTemplate for your type.

To create an EditorTemplate:

1) Create a new folder in your Views/Shared folder called Editor Templates

2) In that folder create a new, strongly typed, partial view with the name of your type as the name of the file. E.G Cohort.cshtml could look like:

```
@model Models.Cohort

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ukft, true) <span style="margin-right:8px;">Yes</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ukft, false) <span>No</span> <br />
```

3) In your main view use         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.list)          and razor will render a partial view created in step 2 for each Cohort in the list.

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion. Can you tell me how razor will figure out to render the partial view in the form?

Comment: I'm no expert on what goes on behind the scenes, but when @Html.EditorFor() is called, it looks in the EditorTemplates folder for an editor for the given type. If EditorFor is given a List<T> then it looks for an editortemplate for T and iterates over each item in the List, rendering an EditorTemplate for each member.

Comment: Thanks for that, I replaced my code in the main page with the following: @using (Html.BeginForm("OptedOut", "Home"))
        {   
            
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.list)
    
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:25px;">
                <input id="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/>
            </div>
        } But it doesn't seem to render the partial view. Are you sure I don't need to do anything else? (aside from creating the strongly typed partial view)