# MVC Rendering a partial view in an EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, model

Further to the solution that was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28764650/4614348), which I tried but didn't work - I wanted to know how razor figures out to render a strongly typed partial view? I did what was suggested but it feels like it's not tied up properly and something is missing.

My "sub" model:

```
public class Cohort
{
    public bool ukft { get; set; }
    public bool ukpt { get; set; }
    ...etc
}
```

My strongly typed partial view:

```
@model Models.Cohort

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.ukft, true) <span style="margin-right:8px;">Yes</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.ukft, false) <span>No</span> <br />
```

My main model (which contains a list of Cohort objects):

```
public class OptOut
{
    public int optOutID { get; set; }
    public bool hasOptedOut { get; set; }        
    public List<Cohort> list { get; set; }

    public OptOut()
    {
        List<Cohort> list = new List<Cohort>();
        list.Add(new Cohort());
        list.Add(new Cohort());
        list.Add(new Cohort());
        list.Add(new Cohort());
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

and then my html:

```
@model Models.OptOut
@using (Html.BeginForm("OptedOut", "Home"))
{   
    //this should supposedly figure out to render a partial view for each element in the list
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.list)

    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:25px;">
        <input id="confirm" type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're just missing the connection between `EditorFor` and your partial view. While `EditorFor` *does* use partial views, more appropriately, it uses what's called "editor templates". These are just partial views whose location and filename follow a particular convention.

Namely, your partial view should go in `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`. (Create the directory. It doesn't exist by default.) Then, it should be named after the type it should be utilized with. Here, that's `Cohort`, so the final path and name should be:

```
Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Cohort.cshtml
```

Then, `EditorFor` will see that you have a list of `Cohort`s and use the `Cohort.cshtml` editor template to render each item in the list.